# Odoo 10 MFG & Module General questions

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-7, odoo-10

We are small manufacturing factory and currently we are using OpenERP 7 for our production needs. We have several customized modules to maintain our business workflow. After release of Odoo 10 as it has a lot useful features, however there are still some basic questions about the general process. So my questions are:

**1. Multi-Level BOM Import from XLS:** is there an opportunity in Odoo 10 to create multi level BOM for Product based on XLS import? Currently we use BOM exported from CAD Software and 1 sub-assembly can contain 250-1000 lines/items of produced and purchased parts.

**1A. Flexible BOM or keep record of every new BOM revision in product.** Is there a way to have 'flexible' BOM for the products which we produce? In both OpenERP and Odoo 10 BOM is linked to a Product card and is fixed, when in our current production we use a modified module, where we use product as a reference only and upload multi level XLS BOM each time we produce it as well as manufacturing drawings and other files.

**2. M/O and sub-assemblies:** what's the standard way of splitting multi-level product in Odoo 10? Do you keep all sub-assemblies in 1 M/O or you have 1 M/O for each sub-assembly? For instance I have a product with 5 level BOM, my top level can have up to 15 major sub-assemblies, each sub-assembly will have it's sub-assemblies as well as purchased and produced parts

**3. Routing steps from XLS BOM:** with our production worklflow we have work steps (routing) for each individual part/BOM line and sub-assembly in BOM file which we get from CAD Software. How can we use it in Odoo 10?

4. Does Odoo 10 support **multi-language**?

I realize that move over to a Odoo10 from OpenERP 7 is a big step and requires a lot of hours of programming, especially for our company workflow. But I'd like to hear different onions from those who faced same or similar questions to have more smooth transition

thanks to all who will reply, 
Vladimir